# How to disable (and re-enable) notifications on GNOME Shell version 3.8.4 from the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, gnome, gnome-shell

I am running Centos 7 with GNOME-Shell 3.8.4.

I **can** happily disable all notifications from the top-right menu, as pictured:

[image: disabling/enabling GNOME shell notifications via GUI]

I need to do that from the command line, though, because I need to automate that in a script to trigger according to certain circumstances.

Is there any way to do that? Thanks all.

Answer (score 12):

### Newer gnome-shell (~3.10+):

disable:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners false
```

enable:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners true
```

Note that you might need to enable/disable notifications also on a per-app basis, e.g. to disable Nautilus notifications:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications.application:/org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/org-gnome-nautilus/ enable false
```

and to re-enable them:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications.application:/org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/org-gnome-nautilus/ enable true
```

### Old gnome-shell (<3.8 or 3.10):

disable:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications enable false
```

enable:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications enable true
```

Comment: where do you find the relevant keys for these things? For instance, I used `gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.notifications` to find keys, but I couldn't see any `applicaton`, let alone any hint on throwing in the whole `:/org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/org-gnome-nautilus/` bit. This has always seemed like a mystery to me, much like the keys of `RegEdit` in Windows - although I know a lot more about navigating that!

Comment: @oligofren - it's all in the manual (although not easy to figure it out)... this is a relocatable schema (to list all relocatable schemas use `gsettings list-relocatable-schemas`) so you need to provide a path for the schema in the format `SCHEMA [:PATH]` - you get the list of paths  with stuff like `dconf list /org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/ `.

Comment: Install dconf editor. It's like regex for gnome-based shells.

Comment: ...and for me to get rid of the current "printer added" notification which is blocking my video playlist call `pkill gjs`